# Mongoose returns empty value when using Model.find

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to verify an apiKey which is passed into the url as a parameter. I am then checking that this apiKey is in the database by doing a Model.find({}) with mongoose. I then have a callback function using `key` as a parameter which I would expect to be null if the apiKey isnt in the database.

Unfortunately all I am getting is an empty value, which prints nothing to the console:

See code below but my console logs this, see how the key value being returned by mongoose is empty, not null.

```
key: 
current: null
error: null
```

```
coffeeRouter.get('/', (req, res) => {

    const currentUser = req.user;
    const incomingApiKey = req.query['apiKey'];

    console.log('Body: ' + incomingApiKey);

    User.find({ apiKey: incomingApiKey }, function(err, key) {

        console.log('key: ' + key);
        console.log('current: ' + currentUser);
        console.log('error: ' + err)

        if((incomingApiKey === undefined || !key) && !currentUser) {
            console.log('unauthenticated');
            res.render('display.hbs', {currentUser});
        } else {
            Coffee.find({})
                .then(coffees => {
                    console.log('authenticated');
                    console.log(coffees)
                    res.render('display.hbs', { coffees, currentUser });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err.message);
                });
        }

    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })

});
```

Comment: It seems like something is up with how you're getting query params from your route.. What does the console show for `console.log('Body: ' + incomingApiKey)` ?

Comment: Look like mongoose didn't find any match

Comment: What is your `console.log('Body: ' + incomingApiKey);` ?

Comment: incomingApiKey works, it returns the api key but i'm not sure why the key parameter in the mongoose call back is just empty, as in no value

Comment: @ajnauleau are you sure that apiKey exists in your database? If you are grabbing it from the request without issue, I suspect the API key does not exist in your database.